# Is this demo site using media queries or responsive tables?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, tablet

I have been trying to figure it out for myself with no luck. I've been getting a lot of inspiration from online Korean retail shops. Examples:

http://ecdemo96168.cafe24.com/

http://ecdemo72744.cafe24.com/

I've looked at the CSS and see nothing. The sites looks exactly the same on desktops, phones, and tablets, landscape and portrait. Is Javascript being used somewhere?

What are the designers doing to get this to work correctly? I'm asking because my site currently needs an overhaul. I want to have the site look the same on all devices. I'm not interested in having a mobile version of my site.

If you could point me in the right direction I would be greatly appreciated. If I can't figure it out myself I would like to be able to convey to the coder/designer what exactly I need my site to do and how it should be coded.

Comment: ummmmm... just do nothing?

Comment: Mobile browsers' default behavior is to render a site simply zoomed out to fit the screen, unless you actually instruct them to behave otherwise. If that's what you want, make sure your site doesn't have a `<meta name="viewport">` element.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your site to change, set the `min-width`. For example, if your site is set at `width:1024px;` add `min-width:1024px;` and your site will look the same on all devices.

Include that in your wrapper div that holds all of your site together.